# Matrix to dictionaries conversion

Tags: python, csv, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I have a CSV file with 2 columns. I want to store 1st column as key and 2nd as value in dictionary and store it in as output file.

```
import math
import numpy
import csv
from decimal import *
#opening Result file with 
open('output.csv','rb') as file:
  contents = csv.reader(file)
#storing content of Result file in matrix
matrix = list()
    for row in contents:
    matrix.append(row)
lookup = dict(matrix) # Storing 2 columns of matrix as key:value in dictionary
# open a new csv file for writing.
csv_out = open('MPA.csv', 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)``
csv_out.close()
```

I wrote this code which is not working generating desired output.

Comment: What output are you expecting and what does the code generate. Does it throw some error or generate wrong results..

Comment: I want it to write a output csv file with key n value. it produces a blank output file.

Comment: But your input already is a csv file with `key, value` columns, so how is your output different?

Comment: Thats what I dont know

Comment: nothing was written using mywriter. That's why nothing comes out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import json

with open('test.csv') as f:
  with open('MPC.json', 'w') as g:
    json.dump(dict([(v[0], v[1]) for v in csv.reader(f)]), g)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are creating a csv.writer but not writing anything to the file.That is the reason for empty file. Add the below line before closing the file:

```
csv_out = open('MPA.csv', 'wb')
mywriter.writerows(lookup.items())  # Add this line.
csv_out.close()
```

If you want data separated by **tabs** instead of **commas** replace this:

```
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
```

by:

```
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: O thank u so much. it wrote a file. but removed all the duplicate keys and their corresponding values
like file was like that earlier
RAB10 -0.016575
MEF2C -0.019655
SP2 1.24E-01
SP2 0.18870625
SP2 0.0879425
ICK -0.02534625
JAG1 -0.01105125
but now it becomes
FOXQ1 -0.0905225
CBLB -0.00853
PPP2R2D 0.117835
SP2 0.0879425
SP4 -0.02329625
PPP2R2C 0.138485
MUC4 0.0942
MGEA5 -0.020625
means SP2 was repeated now its been removed